# How to authenticate user with specific role in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication

```
SecurityConfiguration

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;

    @Autowired
    CustomSuccessHandler successHandler;

    @Autowired
    CustomFailureHandler failureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    CustomBeanDefinition customBeanDefinition;


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService = customBeanDefinition.jpaUserDetails();
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/book/index").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin()
                .successHandler(successHandler)
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureHandler(failureHandler)
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout().permitAll();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/icon/**");
    }
}

CustomUserDetailService

@Service
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getUserAuthority(user.getRoles());
        UserDetails userDetails = buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
        return userDetails;
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getUserAuthority(Set<Role> userRoles) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> roles = new HashSet<>();
        for (Role role : userRoles) {
            roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getAuthority()));
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(roles);
    }

    private UserDetails buildUserForAuthentication(User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }
}

CustomBeanDefinition

@Configuration
public class CustomBeanDefinition {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService jpaUserDetails() {
        return new CustomUserDetailService();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}

UserService

@Service
public class UserService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository,
                       RoleRepository roleRepository, BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    public void save(String username, String email, String password, String name) {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            user = new User();
            user.setName(name);
            user.setUsername(username);
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(password));
            user.setActive(true);
            Role role = roleRepository.findByAuthority("ADMIN");
            user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(role)));
            userRepository.save(user);
            System.out.println("...user saved with ADMIN role");
        }
    }
}
```

In my application user is currently being saved successfully and binding with specific role.

However, when i try to authenticate my application with saved user, it never goes on success handler, it redirects me on failure handler. 
It looks like authentication is not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Logs? Exception messages?

Comment: Also, place a breakpoint in the failure handler

Comment: how r u trying to authenticate? are u calling some rest endpoint? where is that rest endpoint code?

Comment: @efekctive no exception are comming

Comment: @pvpkiran
No, i am not calling any other rest endpoint. It is just basic authentication in web mvc

Comment: Not even on the console via log4j? A breakpoint in the handler will tell you what is going on

Comment: Put a debug point in loadUserByUsername() and check whether the user is properly identifying

Comment: I have debugged the application and got 'Bad credential Exception'. But i have checked in my DB credentials are correct.

Comment: @efekctive

please refer images
https://imgur.com/BPDGyW7

https://imgur.com/4Ukp0os

Comment: Did you print the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
 at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:93)
 at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:166)
 at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175)
 at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:195)
.

Comment: In the post is easier to read

Comment: "Thrown if an authentication request is rejected because the credentials are invalid. For this exception to be thrown, it means the account is neither locked nor disabled." From the docs. Could you inspect the credentials at the breakpoint and compare them with what you have in the database?

Comment: @efekctive
imgur.com/4Ukp0os 
please refer link, i put a breakpoint in loadUserByUsername and got credentials and they are being matched what i have stored in database.

Comment: If you could place everything in the post itself by editing would be better

Comment: Are you sure the list of granted authorities has elements?

Answer (score -1):

Change your Security Configuration, configure() method like below,

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailService).
        passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}
```

Comment: Yes i've done this and it is still not authenticating.